# Theos won't work on my iPad 3

Tags: ios, ipad, makefile, jailbreak, theos

I installed theos successfully(Installed perl,Gnu-c-compiler,ios toolchain,etc) on my ipad 3 which is running on ios 6.1.2 and now when i am trying to make tweaks "Make package install" it shows errors. I started my Google Search Journey again and finally came here.
This is the code for a tweak called Respring Notifier-->

My Tweak.xm-->

```
 #import <SpringBoard/SpringBoard.h>

 %hook SpringBoard

-(void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(id)application 
{
    %orig;

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"RespringNotifier" 

        message:@"Respring Complete! Welcome Back!" 

        delegate:nil 

        cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" 

        otherButtonTitles:nil];

    [alert show];

    [alert release];
}

%end
```

I believe that there is nothing wrong with the code.

and this is my makefile-->

```
include theos/makefiles/common.mk

TWEAK_NAME = RespringNotifier

RespringNotifier_FILES = Tweak.xm

RespringNotifier_FRAMEWORKS = UIKIT

include $(THEOS_MAKE_PATH)/Tweak.mk
```

**And i inserted these lines in makefile a few hours ago at the top before "include theos/makefiles/common.mk"-->**

> export ARCHS =armv7 armv7s arm64
>
> export TARGET = iphone:clang:6.1.:6.1

- I have attached an image where it shows the number of errors when creating a tweak.

Here's the link-->  **https://i.stack.imgur.com/8OWH1.jpg**

Please Help.

Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

When using an iOS device as a build machine, it is best to not use the root user when compiling; use root privileges only to install your package.

To provide more verbose error messages, use 'make messages=yes'. This will provide more context with which to find where the problem is.